# Finding the most dense n*n sub matrix in a sparse matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse square matrix with the side 2*n.

eg.

```
1,0,0,1,0,1
0,1,1,1,0,1
1,0,0,0,1,1
0,0,1,1,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,1,0
```

And i need an efficient way to find a sub matrix with a size of n*n with the largest amount of 1s.

I have found various ways to do it but none faster then O(n^4). I've also found faster ways without the requirement that the sub matrix needs to be n*n.

EDIT:
The submatrix has to be contiguous,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your claim of an O(n^4)-time algorithm, I'm assuming that the submatrix has to be contiguous, as otherwise the problem is NP-hard (it's harder than detecting a biclique). For an O(n^2)-time algorithm, it suffices to do O(n^2)-time preprocessing that enables O(1)-time queries of the form "given `a, b, c, d`, compute `sum_{i=a}^b sum_{j=c}^d X[i,j]`".

Given the array `X[1..m,1..n]`, compute an array `Y[0..m,0..n]` as follows.

```
initialize Y to the zero array
for i from 1 to m
    for j from 1 to n
       Y[i,j] = Y[i-1,j] + X[i,j]
    end
end
for i from 1 to m
    for j from 1 to n
       Y[i,j] = Y[i,j-1] + Y[i,j]
    end
end
```

Now, `Y[c,d] = sum_{i=1}^c sum_{j=1}^d X[i,j]`. To compute `sum_{i=a}^b sum_{j=c}^d X[i,j]`, use inclusion-exclusion: `Y[c,d] - Y[a-1,d] - Y[c,b-1] + Y[a-1,b-1]`.

Comment: This doesn't seem sufficient. There are still ((2n)C(n))^2 choices for nxn submatrices. You've described how you can evaluate the score for each one in O(1) time, given O(n^2) preprocessing, but there are still a lot of choices to enumerate. This "integral image" approach is only appropriate when the matrix is spatially arranged (as in an image). But here, a "submatrix" is typically defined to be the elements selected by any possibly non-contiguous subset of rows and subset of columns.

Comment: @TimothyShields I'm assuming that the submatrix has to be contiguous, since the asker claimed an O(n^4) algorithm and the noncontiguous variant is NP-hard by reduction from biclique.

Comment: It might be a good idea to state that assumption though, because it's possible the asker's O(n^4) claim is just wrong.